# How to get Neo4j 2.2 Auth/API Token

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

Is there a way to retrieve the API token from the REST API?

---

I want to use the py2neo set_auth_token method.

A blog post stated that the server command would return the api token but it does not.

```
:server connect
```

It only lists my user.

I installed a completely new Neo4j 2.2 and did not change any configuration. Unforntunately the docs are not very detailed in regards to the api token feature or i did not find the correct page. All i found was: http://neo4j.com/docs/snapshot/rest-api-security.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toke based approach was removed in M4.
Just use username and password

Comment: You should give more information, this is a poor answer in my opinion (no offense ;-) ). Please explain HOW to pass username and password to the header and in which format). FYI: Authentication: Basic base64encoded. I had the same problem in PHP and it did not help. Frustrating.

Comment: Normal authentication is no problem. The question targeted the api token authentication and this way of authenticating was removed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to passe an `base64` encoded string of `username:password` in the request headers as `Authentication: Basic bAZenKo0dedString==`.

Example request with username foo, password bar (using Postman)

[image: Postman demo]

The string `Zm9vOmJhcg==` being a base64 encoded value of the string `foo:bar`

[image: Encode in base64]

Regards !